# Using component-scan in a web project

Tags: spring-mvc, eclipse-wtp

I have an Eclipse "Dynamic Web Project" and a Tomcat server configured in Eclipse to use that project.  I have a file extension mapped to a servlet, and in the servlet config I have a component-scan element setup like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.web" />
```

When my web server starts up, I see this error message in the log:

```
May 6, 2011 9:50:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet cap
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource path [C:\...\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes\com\mycompany\web] does not denote a directory
```

That directory does not exist (except in the packaged .war file).  However, the com.mycompany.web package does exist.

Is there another way to do a component-scan?  It needs to either look in another folder, or somehow find it in my project or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible to do a component-scan in this way.  It does a directory listing, which I guess isn't possible when the class files aren't physically located where Spring is expecting.  I solved this just by not using a component-scan, and listing the controllers in the spring config like this:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<bean class="com.mycompany.web.MyController"/>
```

Annotations in the controller still work, so listed the controllers manually is the only extra step.

Answer (score 1):

it's possible to do what you want, but you need a little extra configuration.

You can annotate your classes with @Controller or @Repository or other Spring stereotype annotations and Spring will pick them up automatically.

Or you can give `context:component-scan` a bit more info. Example:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.web">
    <!-- scan all classes in the com.mycompany.web package (but
         not in subpackages) -->
    <context:include-filter type="aspectj" expression="com.mycompany.web.*"/>


    <!-- or if you want to include subpackages this config scans all
         classes in com.mycompany.web.special and in its subpackages
         (that's what the ..* means) -->
    <context:include-filter type="aspectj" expression="com.mycompany.web.special..*"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Finally, if you don't like using aspectj, context:include-filter's `type` can be a regular expression, custom annotation, etc. See [this link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters) for more info.